# Does my "six or eight" rule for "raising one" make sense?

Tags: bridge, bidding

I was taught to raise partner's "one of a major" bid to two with six high card points.
A variation of the rule that I learned recently was eight "points" counting distribution.
So over a bid of one heart, a holding like the following might qualify:
♠ 432 ♡ K842 ♢ J752 ♣ 63

There are four honor points, and I was taught to add one for the king of hearts after partner opened it, bringing the total to five.

I add two more points for the fourth trump and an additional point for the club doubleton (these represent ruffing values), bringing the total to eight.

Whether or not they agree with my "math," most modern experts would raise one heart to two hearts, right?

Now supposing I have the "worst" six high card point holding:
♠ Q842 ♡ 432 ♢ Q75 ♣ Q63

There is no honor (and no intermediate cards) in the bid heart suit, and the distribution is 4-3-3-3.

Should I pass on the theory that "six" is really five?

Answer (score 2):

Look for excuses to raise when you have a fit with partner, particularly in a major suit. With the first hand, raise to 2H. With the second hand, also raise to 2H.

If partner bids game with a balanced 18-count, you haven't gone down yet, and even if you eventually do you may have talked opponents out of bidding their own profitable partscore.